# in python what is the / operator doing in the following code

Tags: python

i ran the following code and got no errors

```
def setup_static_routes(app):
    app.router.add_static('/static/',
                          path=PROJECT_ROOT / 'static',
                          name='static')
```

but if i run

```
PROJECT_ROOT="a"
path=PROJECT_ROOT / 'static'
```

i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    path=PROJECT_ROOT / 'static'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

what is the / operator doing in the first example that doesn't throw an error

code found at https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v3.0.1/tutorial.html

Answer (score 5):

This script probably assumes a variable of type `Path`, in which case `/` is defined as path concatenation. Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path
PROJECT_ROOT = Path("a")
path=PROJECT_ROOT / 'static'
```